# problems with authentication keyclaok authentication, in next + typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm doing a project in next with TS using the react-oidc-context lib
and I can even authenticate myself, but when I try to enter one of the pages created without authenticating I can.
ex: localhost:3000/Profile
I can log in without having to authenticate, if I authenticate myself it goes straight to her too.

the codes are like this

src/service/auth.tsx
`
import { UserManager, UserManagerSettings } from "oidc-client-ts";

```
export const authConfig: UserManagerSettings = {
  authority: process.env.KEYCLOAK_AUTH!,
  client_id: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID!,
  client_secret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET!,
  redirect_uri: process.env.KEYCLOAK_REDIRECT_URI!,
  response_type: process.env.KEYCLOAK_RESPONSE_TYPE!,
  scope: process.env.KEYCLOAK_SCOPE!,
  metadata: {
    issuer: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER,
    jwks_uri: process.env.KEYCLOAK_JWKS_URI,
    authorization_endpoint: process.env.KEYCLOAK_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT,
  }
};


export const userManager = new UserManager(authConfig)
```

`

src/app/page.tsx
`
"use client"

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { authConfig, userManager } from '../services/auth'
import { UserManager, User } from 'oidc-client-ts';
import { AuthProvider } from 'react-oidc-context';

export default function Home() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  console.log('valor do usuario: ' + user)
  useEffect(() => {


    userManager.getUser().then((user) => {
      if (user) {
       setUser(user);
      }
    });
  }, [userManager]);

  const handleLogout = () => {
   console.log('(handleLogout) valor do usuario: ' + userManager)

    userManager.signoutRedirect();
  }

  const handleLogin = () => {
    const userManager = new UserManager(authConfig)
    console.log('(handleLogin) valor do usuario: ' + userManager)
    userManager.signinRedirect();
  }

  console.log('(fora) valor do usuario: ' + userManager.getUser())
  return (

    <div>
      <AuthProvider>
        <h1>Logado</h1>
      </AuthProvider>
      {user ? (
         <div>
          <p>Olá {user.profile.given_name}!</p>
          <button onClick={handleLogout}>Sair</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
      )}
     </div>
  );
}
```

`

src/pages/Perfil/index.tsx
`
import Link from "next/link"
import { AuthProvider } from "react-oidc-context"

```
export default function Home() {
 return (
    <main>
      <h1>Ola mundo 2</h1> <br />
      <Link href={"/"}>Voltar</Link>
      <AuthProvider>
        <h1>Logado</h1>
      </AuthProvider>

    </main>

  )
}
```

`

NOTE: I know that my folder structure is very small and that I have to improve, but this is my first experience in a project like this

I've already tried using the react-auth, next-auth lib.
With the lib I'm using, I've now made more progress, but the user is still null, that is, I can't treat it in any way, it doesn't pass if/else and I can't even see the user's name or anything.